# nHibernate, join & ICriteria and restriction issue

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have following table structure

**Table-1  users**

- Userid
- Name
- Company
- Email

**Table-2   location**

- Userid(fkey)
- code
- Location
- Statusid(fkey)

**Userid+code+location=unique key**

**Table-3  status**

- Statusid
- Statusdescription
- For table1. Hbn was written previosly.
- it’s also having complex search criteria on name & company+ other (I have not mentioning here for clarity sake)
- Search on users is already happening for user using ICriteria & Restrictions.
- Now we have new functionality where table2 & table3 has been introduced.
- we have to return user info from table1 +  location and status also. we want to reuse existing search logic + these new criteria’s via mapping userid and statusid with the parent tables 
     and matching  code and location (passed from UI)

•   Not sure how to go about it. I have define simple hbns for these two table but without any join.

how to specify new hbn with join so that i can select the particular column from db (if possible)

Secondly how to specify new criteria for new tables.

Comment: Please post your classes and mappings.